Connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ have at most one point
Given a set $A \subset \mathbb{Q}^{n}$ with #$A > 1$, is it possible to find $s \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $r \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ such that $a_1 \in B(s,r), a_2 \in \operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}^{n} - B(s,r))$ and $A \cap \partial B(s,r) = \varnothing$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in A$? I want to show that connected sets of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ have at most one point, so I'm trying to adapt the proof of case $n = 1$. If we can find such $s$ and $r$, we can write $A$ as
$$A = (A \cap B(s,r)) \cup (A \cap \operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}^{n} - B(s,r)),$$
which would imply that it cannot be connected. If this approach does not work, I would appreciate a hint.

$\mathbb Q^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.

@Ulli which, as far as I know, requires the very difficuly Sierpiński theorem. A cannon to kill a fly.

@freakish Sure, just for this statement, it is overkill. But for a lot of other facts, it might still be good to know. And yes, I'm also not aware of a direct proof.

Your approach most probably works.
For an alternative that uses the case $n=1$, take $A\subset \mathbb{Q}^n$ to be a non-empty connected set.
As the projections $\pi_i:\mathbb{Q}^n\to\mathbb{Q},\, 1\leq i\leq n$ are continuous we have that $\pi_i(A)$ are all (non-empty) connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$. This means that, for each $1\leq i\leq n$,  $\pi_i(A)=\{a_i\}$ for some $a_i\in\mathbb{Q}$, which implies that $A=\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\}$.

Nice solution! Much easier than what I was trying to do.

I assume you are using the Euclidean distance. Take any two points $a_1,a_2\in A$. Let $s=a_1$ and $r=\frac{\pi}{4} \|a_1-a_2\|$. We can write $r$ as $\pi \sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ since $a_1$ and $a_2$ have rational coordinates. Now $a_2$ is outside the ball. Now suppose that some rational point $a_3$ is on the boundary of $B(s,r)$. Since $\|a_3-a_1\|^2$ is rational we can write $\|a_3-a_1\|=\sqrt{\frac{c}{d}}$. Since $a_3$ is on the boundary of the ball, this would imply that $\|a_3-a_1\|=\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$, or rewriting this gives $4c^{2}q^{2}-p^{2}d^{2}\pi=0$. The last equation is impossible since $\pi$ is transcendental (e.g. it cannot be the solution to a polynomial with integer coefficients). So there are no rational points on the boundary of the ball.

The (euclidean) ball is maybe not the most ergonomic choice of neighbourhood here, although it does work.
I would prefer the following: Pick $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)$ in $A$ such that $a\neq b$. Because $a\neq b$, there must be some $k$ such that $a_k\neq b_k$. Now pick an irrational number $r$ bewtween $a_k$ and $b_k$. Now note that the two sets
$$
A_+ = A\cap \{x\in \Bbb Q \mid x_k > r\}\\
A_- = A\cap \{x\in \Bbb Q \mid x_k > r\}
$$
are clopen in $A$, they cover all of $A$, and one of them contains $a$, the other contains $b$.

Basically a "dumbed down" version of Julio Puerta's answer.
